# autodesk forge application Upload failed with 400 error

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have create application of autodesk forge reference
https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-configurator-inventor
application run on web. While trying to upload zip file throw me below error  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsdNr.png)

is there possibility of authentication error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Authentication error. 400 error means bad request, authentication is fine, rest of the things like query params or body is not in the proper format. Please refer documentation and try in rest client like postman.